# Using Jensen's inequality to prove another inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, inequality, convex-analysis, expectation

Suppose $u(\cdot)$ and $v(\cdot)$ are two differentiable, strictly increasing, and strictly concave real functions. Specifically, $v(\cdot)$ is "more concave" than $u(\cdot)$ in the sense that there exists an increasing and strictly concave function $\phi(\cdot)$ such that $v(x)=\phi(u(x))$ at all $x$. It is also equivalent to
\begin{equation}
\frac{v''(x)}{v'(x)}<\frac{u''(x)}{u'(x)} \textrm{ for any }x\,.
\end{equation}

Let $p_i\in(0,1), \sum_{i\in I}p_i=1$ be probabilities and $|I|>2$. Let $x_i$ and $y_i$ be strictly positive for all $i\in I$. Assume
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i\in I}p_ix_i<\sum_{i\in I}p_iy_i,
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i\in I}p_iu(x_i)=\sum_{i\in I}p_iu(y_i).
\end{equation}

Conjecture:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i\in I}p_iv(x_i)>\sum_{i\in I}p_iv(y_i).
\end{equation}
I believe this is right (after trying many numerical examples) and I think a clever use of Jensen's inequality (or its variants) will do this. But I'm stuck on doing it formally. Any hints/thoughts on providing a formal proof?

Remark: this is related to my other post: [Proving an inequality of the expectation of concave functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2581760/proving-an-inequality-of-the-expectation-of-concave-functions)

Update: after some more attempts, I believe some techniques in convex analysis would be helpful. Geometrically, the middle equation represents a hyperplane in the $R^{|I|}$ space, and the desired result (very roughly) says that a concave transformation of that hyperplane should be separated from a convex transformation of it.

To be clear, I wasn't saying the conjecture should be generally true. Any thoughts on finding any sufficient conditions to make it work would be very helpful.

Comment: Should it really be $|I| > 2$?

Comment: Yes, I've already managed to prove the case of $|I|=2$, and I believe it's true for $|I|>2$ as well.

Comment: Then it's induction.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I don't think a usual induction argument works here because starting for $|I|=3$ one couldn't write the inequalities in a way that the $|I|=2$ case can handle, due to the non-linearity of $u(\cdot)$ and $v(\cdot)$.

Comment: The cardinality of $I$ is finite, infinite countable or uncountable?

Comment: It's countable --- could be 3, 4, 5, etc. Could be either finite or infinite (I don't think this matters). If can prove for $|I|=3$, should be easy to extend further.

Answer (score -2):

The reverse inequality holds. A  differentiable  function of one variable is concave on an interval $J$ if and only if the function lies below all of its tangent, i.e., 
$$f(x) \leq f(y) + f'(y)(x-y)$$
for all $x,y\in J$. In particular, if $f′(c) =0$, then $c$ is a global maximum  of $f(x)$.

Applying this for $v$, we have
$$p_i(v(x_i) - v(y_i)) \le p_i v'(y_i)(x_i-y_i)$$ for all $p_i\in(0,1)$ and all $i\in I$.

Summing up over $i$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i\in I}p_i(v(x_i) - v(y_i)) &\le \sum_{i\in I} p_i v'(y_i)(x_i-y_i) \\
&\le  \sum_{i\in I} p_i |v'(y_i)|(x_i-y_i) \qquad \text{since} \,\,  w\le |w|, \forall w \in \mathbb{R} \\
&\le \min_i |v'(y_i)|\sum_{i\in I} p_i  (x_i-y_i) <0.
\end{align}
The second inequality holds since $v$ is increasing so that  $|v'|=v'$ iff $v'>0$.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the second inequality in the last part? if $x_i-y_i < 0$, we can't conclude that $w(x_i-y_i) \le |w|(x_i-y_i)$.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure if the second inequality in your proposed answer is correct, as the above comment also suggested. More generally, as I stated in the conditions of my initial question, we can surely have $\sum_{i}p_iu(x_i)=\sum_{i}p_iu(y_i)$ for a concave function $u(\cdot)$. This means one can't generally prove ``the reserve inequality holds.''

Comment: @induction601 Right, the second inequality holds in one and only one case $v'>0$ which is already happen since $v$ is increasing i,e,  $v'>0$ and this implies that $|v'|\ge v'\ge0$

Comment: @mwomath But still the second inequality in your proposed answer is not true because $x_i-y_i$ is negative for some $i$'s...

Comment: Dear Your conjecture is wrong, it should be reversed.

Comment: @mwomath the conjecture may be right or wrong but I still didn't see your answer to be correct. As I said and other people also pointed out the second inequality in your proposed answer is clearly not correct. Could you provide a different argument to support your claim. Thanks.