# Proving an inequality of the expectation of concave functions?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, inequality, convex-analysis, expectation

Suppose $u(\cdot)$ and $v(\cdot)$ are differentiable, strictly increasing, and strictly concave real functions. Specifically, $v(\cdot)$ is "more concave" than $u(\cdot)$ in the sense that there exists an increasing and strictly concave function $\phi(\cdot)$ such that $v(x)=\phi(u(x))$ at all $x$. It is also equavelent to 
\begin{equation}
\frac{v''(x)}{v'(x)}<\frac{u''(x)}{u'(x)} \textrm{ for any }x\,.
\end{equation}

Let $f(\cdot)$ and $g(\cdot)$ be (well-behaved) two *fixed* real functions on a *fixed* probability measure space ($\Sigma, H, Pr$). The $\sigma-$algebra satisfies the usual conditions. Assume
\begin{equation}
\int h(\cdot)f(\cdot) < \int h(\cdot)g(\cdot)\,,
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\int h(\cdot)u(f(\cdot)) = \int h(\cdot)u(g(\cdot))\,,
\end{equation}
where $h(\cdot)$ is the density function over the probability space.

Conjecture:
\begin{equation}
\int h(\cdot)v(f(\cdot)) > \int h(\cdot)v(g(\cdot))\,.
\end{equation}

Update: thanks to @zhoraster who provided a potential and very clever answer, see below. That answer seems to change my initial question a little bit by considering two different probability distributions on the two sides of the inequalities (in the counter-example he gave). I accordingly updated the wording of my initial conjecture to make it mathematically more precise --- the probability distribution is fixed on both sides.

Also, I'm not sure if the following (weaker) conjecture is true or not: [Using Jensen's inequality to prove another inequality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2581422/using-jensens-inequality-to-prove-another-inequality)

Answer (score 1):

Take any two probability distributions $f$ and $g$ such that 
$$
E[f] = E[g]\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
E[u(f)] = E[u(g)]\tag{2}
$$

Then your conjecture would imply$^*$ that 
$$
E[v(g)] = E[v(f)]\tag{3}
$$
for any $v$, which is "more concave" than $u$, consequently, $f$ and $g$ are identically distributed. So it follows from your conjecture that (1) and (2) imply the equality in distribution. Obviously, this can't be true.

Similarly, your another conjecture is false, one just needs to adjust the counterexample a little bit to make the probabilities equal.

---

Here is a particular example:

The distribution of $f$: $6$ with probability $0.01$, $-6$ with probability $0.01e^{-6}$, $0$ with probability $1-0.01-0.01 e^{-1}$

The distribution of $g$: $1$ with probability $0.1$, $-1$ with probability $0.1e^{-1}$, $0$ with probability $1-0.1-0.1 e^{-1}$

Then 
$$
E[f] = 0.06-0.06e^{-6}< 0.1-0.1e^{-1} = E[g],\\
E[-e^{-f}] = -0.01e^{-6} - (1-0.01-0.01 e^{-6}) - 0.01e^{-6}\cdot e^6 = -1,\\
E[-e^{-g}] = -0.1e^{-1} - (1-0.1-0.1 e^{-1}) - 0.1e^{-1}\cdot e = - 1,
$$
but 
$$
E[-e^{-2f}] = -0.01e^{-6} -(1-0.01-0.01 e^{-6}) - 0.01e^{-6}\cdot e^{12} \\
<  E[-e^{-2g}]= -0.1e^{-1} -(1-0.1-0.1 e^{-1}) - 0.1e^{-1}\cdot e^{2}.
$$

One can make a small adjustment to this example by dividing the probabilities into many small and equal ones, which would give a counterexample to your other conjecture.

---

$^*$ Perturb $f$ a little bit so that (2) still holds, but in (1), the sign changes to $<$. Provided that your conjecture is true, the sign in (3) would change to $>$. Now perturb $f$ "in the opposite direction", so that (2) holds and in (1), the sign changes to $>$. Then the sign in (3) would change to $<$. Then, by continuity, (3) should be equality.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand --- did you basically change my question? As I stated we start with $E[f]<E[g]$. I also don't understand in what sense my conjecture implies the third equation in your proposed answer. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Tuzi, one can use the continuity argument (see updated answer).

Comment: thanks... But could you help me understand the following? It is known from Pratt (Econometrica, 1964) that the following result is true: assume $qx_1+(1-q)x_2<qy_1+(1-q)y_2$ and $qu(x_1)+(1-q)u(x_2)=qu(y_1)+(1-q)u(y_2)$, then for any $v$ more concave than $u$ there must be $qv(x_1)+(1-q)v(x_2)>qv(y_1)+(1-q)v(y_2)$, which is a special case of my conjecture. Looks like your argument also disproves this, which is already shown to be true. Could you elaborate why? Why the new counter-example you gave needs at least three points (in the distribution)?

Comment: @Tuzi, no, my argument does not disprove that. The truth is that you cannot "perturb" two-point distributions with equal probabilities in a manner I wrote. Moreover, one if (1) and (2) hold for two-point distributions with equal probabilities, then usually these distributions are identical. So, indeed, one needs at least three points to construct a counterexample.

Comment: I'm also confused by your statement that "one can make a small adjustment to this example by dividing the probabilities into many small and equal ones, which would give a counterexample to your other conjecture." In that conjecture, I keep the same $p_i$ when I evaluate the two sides of the inequalities (in you current counter-example you changed the probabilities on the two sides; not sure if this matters). Thanks!

Comment: Now for $f$ we have $6$ with probability $0.01$. Instead, we can take very many (say, $N$) values close to $6$ with the same very small probability $\delta$ (so that $N\delta\approx 0.01$). Similarly, we can change other values and probabilities so that all probabilities are equal to $\delta$. Of course, the distributions won't be three-point anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70881/discussion-between-tuzi-and-zhoraster).

Comment: thanks... but did this work for a fixed, finite, N?

Comment: I can't tell immediately whether there is a counterexample (with equal probabilities) for particular *fixed* $N$ or not (the argument above gives *some* $N$).  I suspect there is already one with $N=3$. However, not seeing too much sense in this formulation, I can't impel myself into thinking on it.

Comment: Thanks... But I didn't understand in what sense "the argument above gives some N."  As far as I can see it requires $N\to\infty$. Am I missing anything? And this question has a clear background; I can elaborate more in chat.

Comment: could you see my further elaboration in chat, thanks again!